# Python: mailgun/talon package - "Not A Directory" error on running a test script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, email, mailgun

I am trying out [this open-source library from GitHub called talon](https://github.com/mailgun/talon) to extract important info from e-mail signatures  for a project related to work, and seem to be stuck with the "Not A Directory" error. It's been a long time since I used Python, *so please bear with me.*

This is the example script I want to run that uses the talon module, known as `test.py`:

```
import talon
from talon import quotations

talon.init()

text =  """Reply

-----Original Message-----

Quote"""

reply = quotations.extract_from(text, 'text/plain')
reply = quotations.extract_from_plain(text)
```

On running this using Python 2.7.11 through `python test.py`, I get this error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    talon.init()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/talon/__init__.py", line 13, in init
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/talon/signature/__init__.py", line 39, in initialize
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/egg/talon/signature/learning/classifier.py", line 34, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 590, in load
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
```

I did the same thing but with Python 3.7.1 instead, and I get a similar error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py3.7.egg/talon/signature/learning/classifier.py", line 34, in load
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py3.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 590, in load
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py3.7.egg/talon/signature/data/classifier'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    talon.init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py3.7.egg/talon/__init__.py", line 13, in init
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py3.7.egg/talon/signature/__init__.py", line 39, in initialize
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py3.7.egg/talon/signature/learning/classifier.py", line 38, in load
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py3.7.egg/talon/signature/learning/classifier.py", line 50, in load_compat
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py3.7.egg/talon/signature/data'
```

Did anyone experienced the same problem as I had? Otherwise, what do I need to do?

I think I was using mainly `sudo python setup.py install` in the directory containing the talon repo I downloaded to install it because the work account I have won't let me install Python libraries on its own without root-level access.

EDIT: Someone pointed out to me about `pip install talon`.

This is the output I get for running the command above with the `--user` option:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): talon in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml>=2.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-4.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): regex>=1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/regex-2018.8.29-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scikit-learn>=0.16.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): chardet>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cchardet>=0.3.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cchardet-2.1.4-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cssselect-1.0.3-py2.7.egg (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.10.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): html5lib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html5lib-1.0.1-py2.7.egg (from talon)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): webencodings in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webencodings-0.5.1-py2.7.egg (from html5lib->talon)
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And this is the output on using the `--upgrade` flag:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: talon in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/talon-1.4.5-py2.7.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: lxml>=2.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-4.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg (from talon)
Requirement already up-to-date: regex>=1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/regex-2018.8.29-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg (from talon)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from talon)
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from talon)
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn>=0.16.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg (from talon)
Requirement already up-to-date: chardet>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg (from talon)
Requirement already up-to-date: cchardet>=0.3.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cchardet-2.1.4-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg (from talon)
Requirement already up-to-date: cssselect in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cssselect-1.0.3-py2.7.egg (from talon)
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from talon)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: html5lib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html5lib-1.0.1-py2.7.egg (from talon)
Requirement already up-to-date: webencodings in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webencodings-0.5.1-py2.7.egg (from html5lib->talon)
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.10.0
```

**Unfortunately, this made no difference to the problem above.**

Comment: Since it's failing on `talon.init()`, my guess is that there is a problem with your talon build as you allude to.

Comment: If you don't have root access, you can still install packages with pip by passing the `--user` option. Try: `pip install --user talon`

Comment: Using that made no different, unfortunately.

Comment: sorry, I might have misunderstood. So you actually do have root level access? Then maybe try `sudo pip uninstall talon` then `sudo pip install talon`

Comment: No difference on Python 3, but on Python 2, I have a different error:
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/sklearn/base.py:251: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LinearSVC from version pre-0.18 when using version 0.20.0. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. UserWarning)`